# How to get all the default user groups of a kubernetes cluster

Tags: kubernetes, kubectl

Such as `system:masters`、`system:anonymous`、`system:unauthenticated`.

Is there a way to have all system groups that do not contain external creation, just the system，kubectl command or a list?

I searched the Kubernetes documentation but didn't find a list or a way to get it.

Comment: Which version of Kubernetes did you use? Did you try run `kubectl get serviceaccounts`?

Comment: `kubectl get clusterrole|grep -oP '^system:[^: ]+'  |awk '!a[$0]++'` this or some variation of this command may be helpful.

Comment: @MikołajGłodziak v1.16.9，i want know system user group list， It should not be retrievable by `kubectl get serviceaccounts`

Comment: @P.... not all user groups are not mentioned in clusterrole, i try use this command but `system:masters、system:anonymous、system:unauthenticated` both not in list

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**There is no build-in command to list all the default user groups from the Kubernetes cluster.**

However you can try to workaround in several options:

- You can create your custom script (i.e. in Bash) based on `kubectl get clusterrole` command.
- You can try install some [plugins](https://krew.sigs.k8s.io/plugins/). Plugin [rakkess](https://github.com/corneliusweig/rakkess/blob/master/README.md) could help you:

> Have you ever wondered what access rights you have on a provided kubernetes cluster? For single resources you can use `kubectl auth can-i list deployments`, but maybe you are looking for a complete overview? This is what `rakkess` is for. It lists access rights for the current user and all server resources, similar to `kubectl auth can-i --list`.

See also more information about:

- [kubelet authentication / authorization](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/command-line-tools-reference/kubelet-authentication-authorization/)
- [anonymous requests](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/access-authn-authz/authentication/#anonymous-requests)

Comment: I I'm not currently concerned about the roles bound to a user or user group, just trying to determine what the native kubernetes built-in user groups are, so far I know there are `system:masters, system:anonymous, system:unauthenticated` but I don't know if this is complete, mainly concerned about the built-in user groups

Comment: In this case, the command `kubectl get clusterrole` should help you. You will then be able to see all the roles that are available. As I mentioned. There is no built-in command to display the results you want.

Comment: It looks like this, only role data is available, and even the user groups built into the kubernetes source code are not viewable

Comment: As I have mentioned before - there is no built-in solution to see user groups. You can try achive this by creating custom script or using some plugins.